# Find the domain of the function $f(x)=\dfrac{64+x^2+x}{9x^2+27x+9}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find the domain of the function $f(x)=\dfrac{64+x^2+x}{9x^2+27x+9}$.

I don't know how to start nor how to do it. Please help me!

Comment: Are some parentheses missing ?

Comment: (64+x²+x)/(9x²+27x+9)

Comment: Actually several domains can be *chosen*. So you cannot speak of 'the' domain here allready. They should have asked: find all values in $\mathbb{R}$ that can belong to a chosen domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain of a function is the set of argument values for which the function is defined.

We need to make $\displaystyle\frac{64+x^2+x}{9x^2+27x+9}$ defined

$\displaystyle\implies 9x^2+27x+9\ne0\iff x^2+3x+1\ne0$

Now, the roots of $\displaystyle x^2+3x+1=0$ are $x=\frac{-3\pm\sqrt5}2$ which will make the given function undefined

So, the domain will be  $\left(-\infty, \infty\right)$ excluding those two points i.e.,

$\displaystyle\left(-\infty, \frac{-3-\sqrt5}2\right)\cup\left(\frac{-3-\sqrt5}2,\frac{-3+\sqrt5}2\right)\cup\left(\frac{-3+\sqrt5}2,\infty\right)$

Also observe that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{64+x^2+x}{9x^2+27x+9}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac{64}{x^2}+1+\frac1x}{9+\frac{27}x+\frac9{x^2}}=\frac19$

Comment: i don't understand your last thing

Comment: @user114280, please have a  look into the edited version

Comment: In my view you showed that the domain of $f$ is necessarily a subset of the set you mention. But +1 anyhow. It is probably irrelevant for the OP.

Comment: @drhab, not sure if I've understood your statement. Would you mind a little elaboration

Comment: A prescription like $x\mapsto\sqrt{x}$ or $f\left(x\right)=\sqrt{x}$
does not determine the domain. If context makes
clear that domain is subset of e.g. $\mathbb{R}$ then the prescription
tells you which subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are candidates for being
domain. If $x\mapsto\sqrt{x}$ any subset
of $\left[0,\infty\right)$ is candidate. Union of these candidates
is a candidate itself and is usually labeled as the 'domain' of the
prescribed function. The domain of the function is a part of its definition.
Practicizing this view a function is a triple $\left(X,f,Y\right)$
where $f\subset X\times Y$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Solve the quadratic equation: $$9x^2+27x+9=0\tag{$\star$}$$ The roots of $\text{($\star$)}$ will be the $x$-values where the function $f(x)$ is undefined. (Since division by zero is undefined) You'll then conclude that the domain of the function $f(x)$ is that of all real numbers except the roots of $\text{($\star$)}$.